# Error en migración de Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration

Tengo las siguientes migraciones/tablas: 
Lenguajes

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateLanguagesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('languages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('id');
            $table->string('language')->nullable();
            $table->string('location');
            $table->string('code')->nullable();
            $table->integer('state');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('languages');
    }
}
```

Usuarios

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('id_style')->unsigned();            
            $table->foreign('id_style')->references('id')->on('styles');
            $table->string('username')->unique()->index();
            //$table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('rol');
            $table->integer('status');
            $table->string('ip')->unique();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

Hasta ahi todo bien pero en esta que siguen me salen errores:
Perfiles

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateProfilesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('id');
            //falta
            //aqui deberia deicr que id es compuesta por id_user y id_langauge
            $table->integer('id_user')->unsigned();            
            $table->foreign('id_user')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->string('id_language')->unsigned();            
            $table->foreign('id_language')->references('id')->on('languages');
            //$table->primary('id')->unique('id_user', 'id_language');//PRUEBA POR EJECUTAR
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('profiles');
    }
}
```

ERROR:

```
php artisan migrate 
Migration table created successfully.
Migrating: 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
Migrated:  2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
Migrating: 2019_02_19_201248_create_styles_table
Migrated:  2019_02_19_201248_create_styles_table
Migrating: 2019_02_19_201643_create_users_table
Migrated:  2019_02_19_201643_create_users_table
Migrating: 2019_02_19_202644_create_contacts_table
Migrated:  2019_02_19_202644_create_contacts_table
Migrating: 2019_02_19_203326_create_languages_table
Migrated:  2019_02_19_203326_create_languages_table
Migrating: 2019_02_19_204235_create_profiles_table

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `profiles` add constraint `profiles_id_language_foreign` foreign key (`id_language`) references `languages` (`id`))

  at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Andr3yvlz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668| 

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint")
      /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Andr3yvlz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:458

  2   PDOStatement::execute()
      /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Andr3yvlz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:458

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
MacBook-Air-de-Andres:Andr3yvlz andr3yvlz$
```

Y con `-v`

```
php artisan migrate -v
Migration table created successfully.
Migrating: 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
Migrated:  2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
Migrating: 2019_02_19_201248_create_styles_table
Migrated:  2019_02_19_201248_create_styles_table
Migrating: 2019_02_19_201643_create_users_table
Migrated:  2019_02_19_201643_create_users_table
Migrating: 2019_02_19_202644_create_contacts_table
Migrated:  2019_02_19_202644_create_contacts_table
Migrating: 2019_02_19_203326_create_languages_table
Migrated:  2019_02_19_203326_create_languages_table
Migrating: 2019_02_19_204235_create_profiles_table

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'unsigned not null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) def' at line 1 (SQL: create table `profiles` (`id` varchar(255) not null, `id_user` int unsigned not null, `id_language` varchar(255) unsigned not null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

  at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Andr3yvlz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668| 

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'unsigned not null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) def' at line 1")
      /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Andr3yvlz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:452

  2   PDO::prepare("create table `profiles` (`id` varchar(255) not null, `id_user` int unsigned not null, `id_language` varchar(255) unsigned not null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'")
      /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Andr3yvlz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:452

  3   Illuminate\Database\Connection::Illuminate\Database\{closure}("create table `profiles` (`id` varchar(255) not null, `id_user` int unsigned not null, `id_language` varchar(255) unsigned not null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'", [])
      /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Andr3yvlz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:657

  4   Illuminate\Database\Connection::runQueryCallback("create table `profiles` (`id` varchar(255) not null, `id_user` int unsigned not null, `id_language` varchar(255) unsigned not null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'", [], Object(Closure))
      /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Andr3yvlz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:624

  5   Illuminate\Database\Connection::run("create table `profiles` (`id` varchar(255) not null, `id_user` int unsigned not null, `id_language` varchar(255) unsigned not null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'", [], Object(Closure))
      /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Andr3yvlz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:459

  6   Illuminate\Database\Connection::statement("create table `profiles` (`id` varchar(255) not null, `id_user` int unsigned not null, `id_language` varchar(255) unsigned not null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'")
      /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Andr3yvlz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php:97

  7   Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::build(Object(Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection), Object(Illuminate\Database\Schema\Grammars\MySqlGrammar))
      /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Andr3yvlz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Builder.php:264

  8   Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder::build(Object(Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint))
      /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Andr3yvlz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Builder.php:165

  9   Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder::create("profiles", Object(Closure))
      /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Andr3yvlz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:237

  10  Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic("create")
      /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Andr3yvlz/database/migrations/2019_02_19_204235_create_profiles_table.php:26

  11  CreateProfilesTable::up()
      /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Andr3yvlz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:360

  12  Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator::Illuminate\Database\Migrations\{closure}()
      /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Andr3yvlz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:367

  13  Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator::runMigration(Object(CreateProfilesTable), "up")
      /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Andr3yvlz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:178

  14  Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator::runUp("/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Andr3yvlz/database/migrations/2019_02_19_204235_create_profiles_table.php")
      /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Andr3yvlz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:147

  15  Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator::runPending([])
      /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Andr3yvlz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:96

  16  Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator::run([])
      /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Andr3yvlz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/MigrateCommand.php:71

  17  Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateCommand::handle()
      /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Andr3yvlz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:29

  18  call_user_func_array([])
      /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Andr3yvlz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:29

  19  Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
      /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Andr3yvlz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:87

  20  Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Object(Closure))
      /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Andr3yvlz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:31

  21  Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), [])
      /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Andr3yvlz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:572

  22  Illuminate\Container\Container::call()
      /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Andr3yvlz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:183

  23  Illuminate\Console\Command::execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
      /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Andr3yvlz/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:255

  24  Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command::run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
      /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Andr3yvlz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:170

  25  Illuminate\Console\Command::run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Andr3yvlz/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:901

  26  Symfony\Component\Console\Application::doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Andr3yvlz/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:262

  27  Symfony\Component\Console\Application::doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Andr3yvlz/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:145

  28  Symfony\Component\Console\Application::run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Andr3yvlz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php:89

  29  Illuminate\Console\Application::run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Andr3yvlz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php:122

  30  

Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
          /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Andr3yvlz/artisan:37
```

Comment: @Dev.Joel pero lo necesito de tipo string.  ya encontre la solucion look: 

en la tabla lenguajes: 
            `$table->string('id');`
            `$table->primary('id');`

y en la tabla perfiles:
`$table->string('id_language');`
`$table->foreign('id_language')->references('id')->on('languages');`

Comment: Sí, ese era el error. No vi bien, `unsigned` es para campos de tipo integer y lo tiene en el campo `string`

Comment: @Dev.Joel si era porque en la tabla lenguajes no estaba definiendo el id como primario, y en la otra le estaba poniendo el `unsigned` a un string

Comment: Siéntase libre de añadir los cambios como respuesta, es totalmente válido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es por incompatibilidad de tipos ya que el método `unsigned()` es propio de los campos de tipo `integer` y lo está añadiendo a un campo de tipo `string`

```
//Error eliminar unsigned
 $table->string('id_language')->unsigned();

 $table->string('id_language');
```

Answer (score 0):

Se debe indicar en la tabla lenguajes la clave primaria ya que al ser de tipo `string`, el Laravel no la reconoce como primaria automaticamente.

Entonces quedaría así :

```
Schema::create('languages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('id');
            $table->primary('id');
            $table->string('language')->nullable();
            $table->string('location');
            $table->string('code')->nullable();
            $table->integer('state');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

y la tabla de perfiles se debe quitar el `unsigned` ya que este campo es unicamente para los tipos `autoincrement` o `enteros`.
Y quedaría así:

```
Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('id');
            $table->integer('id_user')->unsigned();            
            $table->foreign('id_user')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->string('id_language');            
            $table->foreign('id_language')->references('id')->on('languages');
            $table->primary('id')->unique('id_user', 'id_language');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```